# Typescript error when passing const array to generic function

Tags: typescript, generics

I'd like to be able to choose a random element from the SHAPES array, while also keeping it as `const` so that the `Shape` type can be used elsewhere in the code. Ideally, I want to be able to use the below `randomChoice` function for both `const` and non-`const` arrays.

```
const SHAPES = [
  'circle',
  'square',
  'triangle',
] as const;
type Shape = typeof SHAPES[number];

console.log('Available shapes are:');
for (let shape of SHAPES) {
  console.log(`    ${shape}`);
}

function randomChoice<T>(arr: T[]): T {
  let index = Math.floor(arr.length * Math.random());
  return arr[index];
}
console.log('A random shape is:');
console.log(randomChoice(SHAPES));
```

When I run the above, I get this error:

```
C:\ts>npx tsc test.ts
test.ts:18:26 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'readonly ["circle", "square", "triangle"]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'.
  The type 'readonly ["circle", "square", "triangle"]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'any[]'.

18 console.log(randomChoice(SHAPES));
                            ~~~~~~
```

And if I change the last line to this:

```
let choice = randomChoice(SHAPES);
console.log(choice);
```

I get a slightly different error:

```
C:\ts>npx tsc test.ts
test.ts:18:27 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'readonly ["circle", "square", "triangle"]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'unknown[]'.
  The type 'readonly ["circle", "square", "triangle"]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'unknown[]'.

18 let choice = randomChoice(SHAPES);
                             ~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `as const` on `SHAPES` declares it as a `readonly` array. Remove `as const` if you can, or change the function definition to accept `Readonly<T[]>` ([sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAygCQIIAUCicYF4YG0CwAUDDAOTACWATsADYCmpANESaRAI4CuAhlYy2JkoVCjzABzBsyIBdGDwgxQkKAG4iUAJ4AHevAAWPPdhja9IAGbxk6OLjBcAtgCN6VWRsJEVEEAwA6WhAJAApSJAA3HgpaHhcGGAgjPSU%20egAuUgBKL0sQKhhQhlhk430rG1QMbJgAb1ZlcD9A4LCAAxISABI6sr0AX3bcogGiIksuMGAoCnAYKnEAExAnAGEDEApgegAeABUAPlC%20KgyYACV6HhWwWi0D3FlD7PP9%20saSmAowJfoAD1MAFkeFADAFLMECicqFQgvRJGCYAAqGAgsEBRa-VahbIjIT8KBcKhgBSw3A-P7-TyjHzNfz0IIhcJIBbLVZJFL6CgQLL43wMplhLErdabbb0UKIapwPFqIA)):

```
function randomChoice<T>(arr: Readonly<T[]>): T {
  let index = Math.floor(arr.length * Math.random());
  return arr[index];
}
```